# How to get polyline point on click on this point?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I have a polyline, and want to delete some points on right click. So is there a way to get the poly point on rightclick? i can get the coords of the map and compare them with poly array of dots, but i thisn there must be a simple way.

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of a point on the line when you right-click it:

```
polyline.addListener('rightclick', function(polyMouseEvent) {
    var coords = polyMouseEvent.latLng;
});
```

It's a bit trickier to then determine if that point is one of the nodes.  Although according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolyMouseEvent) you can find out *"The index of the vertex beneath the cursor when the event occurred, if the event occurred on a vertex and the polyline or polygon is editable"*.  I seem to recall not having much luck with this though.

And I think you need to delete a section of the path, not just remove a single coordinate from it.  Unless perhaps you completely redraw the polyline each time.

I did something vaguely similar [here](https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2015/10/16/google-maps-editable-polylines/), where I delete sections of the path whenever you right-click on that bit of the polyline.

Answer (score 1):

```
newShape.addListener('rightclick', function (polyMouseEvent) {
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(polyMouseEvent.latLng, this, 0.0001)) {
        var vertex = polyMouseEvent.vertex;
        // alert(vertex)
    }
});
```